# Desencadenar eventos en ventana modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo una ventana modal hecha con bootstrap, dentro tengo un formulario e intento enviar ese formulario  a otro archivo para procesar la información pero el botón no hace nada, me he dado cuenta que el boton para cerrar la ventana modal tiene un atributo llamado data-dismiss   que yo supongo hace que cierre la ventana, existe algún atributo para que se envié el formulario  a demás de ser de tipo submit ?

Este el botón para cerrar la ventana modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

Botón para enviar el formulario

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Save changes</button>
```

Formulario

```
<form name="AddCat"  action="./insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
```

NOTA: el archivo donde se procesa el formulario es servlet

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar el siguiente código

```
$(document).ready(escuchador);

function escuchador(){
        $("input[name='cursBoton']").on("click",function(event) {        
               event.preventDefault();    
              procesar(this);                            
      });       

       $("button[name='cursBoton']").on("click",function(event) {        
             event.preventDefault();    
              procesar(this);            

      });  

}
```

event.preventDefault evitara que por ser submit recargue la pagina

```
function procesar(event){      

var cursBton = $(event).val();
var form = $(event).closest("form");  
 var modal = $("#Agregar");
  if(form.valid())
   {                                        
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize() + "&cursBoton=" + cursBton,
        success: function( response ) {     
            //utilzar response

        }
      });   
  }
```

}

Y envias tu solicitud al servidor a traves de ajax

Answer (score 0):

Perdona no habia leido muy bien tu pregunta.  Lo que puedes hacer es crear una función con javascript y usar la función de bootstrap que cierra el modal `$('#modal').modal('hide')`
Estaria quedando asi:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="cierraModal()" >Save changes</button>
```

y la funcion:

```
function cierraModal(){
  $('form[name="AddCat"]').submit(fuction(e){
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
  });
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el consejo pero no me funciono =( jaja  el modal se queda abierto ademas de que no me redirecciona a ningún lado

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esta forma:

teniendo el botón

```
 <button type="submit" id="btnguardar" class="btn btn-success closeModal">Save changes</button>
```

En ves de utilizar el name(**btnguardar**), usamos el id y una clase css(**closeModal**).

Creas esta funciona anónima de jquery para capturar el submit.

```
$("#btnguardar").submit(function( event ) {});
```

Luego capturas el id, cierras el modal actual y abres otro, todo esto dentro de la función anterior.

```
$(".closeModal").click(function () {
    $(".modal").modal("hide");
    $("#myModal2").modal();
});
```

quedaría así:

```
$("#btnguardar").submit(function( event ) {
    $(".closeModal").click(function () {
        $(".modal").modal("hide");
        $("#myModal2").modal();
    });
});
```

y le agregas la función document ready para que lo cargue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```